# Drawing a movieclip to bitmapdata moves around

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm trying to draw a movieclip to a bitmapdata and have it look the same as if I had just added the movieclip directly to the stage. However the result shifts around. I suspect it has something to do with the origin and bounds but can't figure it out.

http://megaswf.com/s/2441986
(the one on the right is the problem)

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public var movieClip:MovieClip;
        public var bitmapData:BitmapData
        public var bitmap:Bitmap;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);


            // for comparison, this is what I want the result to look like
            movieClip = new skeletonWalk();
            movieClip.x = 200;
            movieClip.y = 200;
            addChild(movieClip); 

            // and this it the problem child
            bitmap = new Bitmap();
            bitmap.x = 300;
            bitmap.y = 200;
            addChild(bitmap);
        }

        private function update(e:Event):void
        {
            var bounds:Rectangle = movieClip.getBounds(movieClip);
            bitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.width, bounds.height, true, 0x0);
            bitmapData.draw(movieClip, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -bounds.x, -bounds.y));
            bitmap.bitmapData = bitmapData;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You draw your movie clip in top left corner of the bitmap, as the clip changes its height when the sword is in the upright position whole thing moves down.

Try to fix bottom edge, not the top edge.

```
bitmapData.draw(movieClip, new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -bounds.x, maxMCheight - (bounds.y + bounds.height)));
//maxMCheight is the height of the clip while the sword is risen
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work using your method. I also had to increase the bitmapdata size to maxMCHeight because it was now getting cut off a little at the bottom.

Comment: Hey, I'm actually still struggling with this. I tried the exact same code on a different animation and check out what happens: http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1339163406 I tried messing with the values but can't seem to find the right combination.

Comment: Check out the bone on the left, it's supposed to fly to the left but on the bitmapdata version it stays in place horizontally. And the arm does a weird thing where it stays low and then suddenly jumps up even though it's supposed to be a smooth motion.